# SQL SERVER Express Connection String for User Instances same on SQL Server Standard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, database-administration, ssms

So SQL Server 2005 Express edition has the following connection string by default, which enables user instances instead of Concurrrent Multi-User Access:

```
Data Source=.\SQLExpress;
   AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\dash.mdf;
   Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

So my question is just simply is this the same for SQL Standard, or SQL Enterprise?

I know the database development aspect, but implementing on a server, I am a rookie.

So on that note, any learning resources you can offer would be highly appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's an Express specific connection string.  The AttachDbFileName directive is only supported by Express.

For a comprehensive reference have a look at [**ConnectionStrings.com**](http://connectionstrings.com)